# How to show the registrations info in the #myTickets div?

Tags: laravel

I have a page "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1" where the user can edit stuff related to his account. The route for this page is:

```
Route::get('/user/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@index',
    'as'   =>'user.index'
]);
```

In the index method of the UserController is just returned the view:

```
 public function index(){
        return view('users.index')->with('user', Auth::user());
    }
```

In this page (http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1) there are some tabs to edit/manage different aspects of the user account (General Info, Login Info, My Tickets).

**Doubt:**

My doubt is in the "#myTickets" tab I want to show the registrations that the user has. So I created a method in the UserController like below. My doubt is how to properly call this method to show this information when the tab "My Tickets" is clicked, how this can be handled in terms of routes. Because as it is the getRegistrations method is not being used.

```
public function getRegistrations(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $registrations = User::find($user->id)->registrations;

        dd($registrations);
        return view('users.index')->with('registrations', $registrations);
    }
```

// tabs links

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray account_options" role="tablist">
     <li class="">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#generalInfo" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">General Info</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#myTickets" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">>MyTickets</span></a>
    </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Then the tabs are like below:

```
 <div class="tab-content  bg-white" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="generalInfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateGeneralInfo')}}" class="clearfix">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            ...
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
        ...
        @foreach($registration as $reg)
        <ul>
          <li>here is to show congress title</li>
          <li>here is to show congress date</li>
          <li>here is to show registration date</li>
          ...
        </ul>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Relevant Models to the question:

```
// Congress model
class Congress extends Model
{
    // A conference has many registration types
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// RegistrationModel
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration (main_participant_id)
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

}

// TicketTypeModel
class TicketType extends Model
{

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}

// user model
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // A user can register in many conferences
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','main_user_id');
    }

}
```

Tables structure:

```
registrations table: id, status, congress_id, created_at
congresses table: id, name, created_at,...
ticket type table:id, name, congres_id, created_at, ....
```

Comment: If you have tabs on the same page then i belive you dont need to separate the registrations, fetch then in index method as pass it along, as the registrations are the part of other tab content.

Comment: Thanks, but the user congress registrations are to show only in the myTickets tab.

Comment: It will show in myTickets tab, just merge getRegistrations with index and pass the registrations to the view.

Comment: Thanks, what you are saying is to put the code in the getRegistrations inside the index method?

Comment: Yes fetch the `Auth::user` registrations data and pass to the index view.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the getRegistrations() and changed the index() to:  "public function index(){ $user = Auth::user(); $registrations = User::find($user->id)->registrations; return view('users.index')->with('user', Auth::user()->with($registrations));}"". But it appears "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'registrations.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `registrations` where `registrations`.`user_id` = 1 and `registrations`.`user_id` is not null)". Do you know why?

Comment: In the registrations table the column name is not "user_id" is "main_user_id" I dont know if that is the issue.

Comment: Indeed its the issue but in you `registrations` relation you can specify the keys.

Comment: Thanks!! Now it appears "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::parseWithRelations() must be of the type array, object given,". Do you know why? Also can you give the answer to accept? Delete the getRegistrations() and put  the code in the index() seems to work.

Comment: Please share you `registrations` relation code, edit you question and put it there.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the models, with the tables structure and also with the info that I want to show in the tab "My Tickets" (congress title, congress date, registration date).

Comment: You are still missing the `User` model, in your `User` model, `registrations` relation you need to pass `foreign_key` `main_user_id`

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $registrations = $user->with('registrations.congress');

    return view('users.index', compact('user', 'registrations'));
}
```

Comment: If you need to get `congres` then eager load it as: `compact('user', 'registrations.congres')`

Comment: The "{{$reg}}" only shows info about the registrations table "{"id":1,"congress_id":1,"main_user_id":1}". Do you know what is necessary to show the congress info like name, date, etc?

Comment: You need another loop to parse reg for every registration to show the info in blade.

Comment: But in the index() or in the page where is the "My tickets" tab?

Comment: In your `@foreach` you need another loop, and for `congres` info you need to eager load `registrations.congres`